# Handling Multiple request on a single resource

Tags: http, concurrency, jetty

Recently I came across a question where it was asked if we have around 1000 users hitting a rest endpoint of a microservice and on this endpoint, it was fetching the same data from some other slow process, how could we optimize the request in this usecase? Caching is the obvious answer but how could it be optimized for large number of concurrent requests ?

Comment: http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/recipes/thunderingherd.html

Comment: Yeah synchronizing the cache to multiple requests should be the only way.. thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Obviously as you say you have to go through the cache options, when you have a single application the fastest way can be Ehcache, it is a fairly simple framework to implement.

But if you want to increase the availability of the service you have to cluster it. For that you have to have a load balancer like nginx, and on the other hand to centralize the cache can be Redis db.

```
               Redis ( cache ) 
                     ^^
Nginx (LB) -> cluster of your app -> Other service
```

Comment: I think the question was about  handling a burst of request on a rest-endpoint backed by a slow service.

Comment: @Cacheable Synchronizes the executions of the method with the same parameters, also saves in memory the response for the next execution.. This way you minimize the request to another application.  org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable